# ocaml hash from mysql

Tags: mysql, csv, hashtable, ocaml

I have a large database (approx. 150 000 records) that I want to embed into an OCaml source code named compute.ml. I am trying (without success) to transform these tables into hashtables and to embed these hastables into a function `compute`, so as to have the binary program run quicly without having to do queries to an external sql database.

I have 2 questions:

- Is there a way to export for once a mysql table into an associative array (Hashtbl) that can be accessed by (or even embedded into) my OCaml function `compute` (itself compiled and used as a binary)?
- Is this hashtable permanently loaded in the function or has it to be re-initiated each time that the function is called within the binary?

I have a mysql table with 142741 records which, exported in CSV format, looks like this:

```
"1";"27";"10";"coco";"0";"730";"1641025";"1641053";"foo";"1";"S";"0"
"2";"27";"11";"kiki";"0";"730";"1641054";"1641083";"bar";"1";"S";"0"
"3";"27";"12";"toto";"0";"730";"1641084";"1641113";"foofoo";"1";"S";"0"
"4";"27";"1";"tata";"0";"730";"1641114";"1641142";"barbar";"1";"S";"0"
...
"142741";"5";"7";"chotto";"0";"1347";"1971472";"1971500";"lastrecord";"1";"S";"0"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have a .csv file `data.csv` containing your mysql table, exported to csv format.
Then in OCaml, I would read and parse this file, once, when the program is launched:

```
let data = read_csv("data.csv")
```

`data` is thus a variable, of type `Hashtbl.t`, containing your 150K records.
Then, an OCaml function (which is called `compute` in your question) uses this variable:

```
let compute x =
  let foo = Hashtbl.find data x in
  ...
```

This way, there are no calls to a MySQL server, the data is read only once when you launch the program, and then each call to the function `compute` uses the already in memory variable `data`.

If you're concerned about reading and parsing the csv file, you might have a look at the `Marshal` module, to store a binary version of the variable `data`.

Note that `read_csv` is not in the standard library, but there is for instance http://csv.forge.ocamlcore.org/ .

Comment: Thanks jrouquie for you precise answer which seems to respond exactly to my needs. I am trying it but unfortunately I cannot make it use the command read_csv (mmsg:" Error: Unbound value read_csv"). I have installed scrupulously the CSV-1.2.3 library from file csv-1.2.3.tar.gz on ~/opt/cvs-1.2.3 of my mutualized server... mybe I did something wrong.

Comment: in fact 'ocamlfind list -describe' gives me a list of libraries among which "csv" but I cannot access to those non-"distributed by OCaml" I have no clue how to install them cleanly! any idea?

Comment: The function you want to use is probably `Csv.load : ?separator:char -> string -> t`, but see the doc for more details. If you have problems installing this library, you should ask another question.

Comment: In fact I did have Ocaml CSV library properly installed (at least the csv.mli and csv.ml sources) but the problem remains of the precise code I should have to transform the CSV file into a proper Hastbl format. I have to say that the only doc I found (none on google) is in the csv.mli file and is not cristal-clear to a quasi-profane as me. Save me from days of painful trial & errors on that would be a very appreciated gesture...

Comment: Usage of the Csv module belongs to another question. Detail what you read and what you tried (including short code excerpts), then state precisely what point is blocking you. Alternatively you can have someone write the code for you, but this won't be free ;-)

Comment: thank, I did that in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368953/installing-an-ocaml-hump-library-on-mutualized-server hoping for help. Do you have link for doc on cvs that I did not find?

Comment: Now I have my csv module installed and compiled. Could you help me understand how I can use this module to produce a Hashtbl and not just a list? when I do 'let data = read_csv("data.csv");; then let foo = Hashtbl.find data x;; I ahe an error of type : Error: This expression has type Csv.t = string list list
       but an expression was expected of type ('a, 'b) Hashtbl.t
Is there a way to produce an actual associative array Hashtbl from this csv module? I did  not find it anywhere in the documenattion.

Comment: Here too, if you haven't solved it already, you will need to post a distinct question.