# installing an Ocaml hump library on mutualized server

Tags: csv, shared-libraries, ocaml

I am trying to use the Ocaml csv library. I downloaded [csv-1.2.3](http://csv.forge.ocamlcore.org/) and followed the installation instructions after installing findlib:

> 1. Uncompress the source archive and go to the root of the package,
> 2. Run 'ocaml setup.ml -configure',
> 3. Run 'ocaml setup.ml -build',
> 4. Run 'ocaml setup.ml -install'

Now I have `META`, `csv.a`, `csv.cma`, `csv.cmi`, `csv.cmx`, `csv.cmxa`, `csv.mli` files in `~/opt/lib/ocaml/site-lib/csv` repertory. The shell command `ocamlfind list -describe` gives `csv A pure OCaml library to read and write CSV files. (version: 1.2.3)` which I believe means that csv is installed properly.

BUT when I add

```
  let data = Csv.load "foo.csv" in
```

in my `compute.ml` module and try to compile it within the larger program package I have the compilation error :

```
File "_none_", line 1, characters 0-1:
Error: No implementations provided for the following modules:
         Csv referenced from compute.cmx"
```

and if I simply type

```
let data = load "foo.csv" in
```

i get :

```
File "compute.ml", line 74, characters 13-17:
Error: Unbound value load
```

I have the same type of errors when I use `Csv.load` or `load` directly in the Ocaml terminal. Would somebody have an idea of what is wrong in my code or library installation?

Comment: show the compilation command line

Comment: it is "make" and makefile is quite large because it is a large program (approx 50 files .ml)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you're using `ocamlfind` for compilation (`ocamlfind ocamlc -package csv ...`), because you have a linking error, not a type-checking one (which would be the case if you had not specified at all where `csv` is). The solution may be, in this case, to add a `-linkall` option to the final compilation line producing an executable, to ask it to link `csv.cmx` with it. Otherwise, please try to use `ocamlfind` and yes, tell us what your compilation command is.

For the toplevel, it is very easy to use `ocamlfind` from it. Watch this toplevel interaction:

```
% ocaml
        Objective Caml version 3.12.1

# #use "topfind";;
- : unit = ()
Findlib has been successfully loaded. Additional directives:
  #require "package";;      to load a package
  #list;;                   to list the available packages
  #camlp4o;;                to load camlp4 (standard syntax)
  #camlp4r;;                to load camlp4 (revised syntax)
  #predicates "p,q,...";;   to set these predicates
  Topfind.reset();;         to force that packages will be reloaded
  #thread;;                 to enable threads

- : unit = ()
# #require "csv";;
/usr/lib/ocaml/csv: added to search path
/usr/lib/ocaml/csv/csv.cma: loaded
# Csv.load;;
- : ?separator:char -> ?excel_tricks:bool -> string -> Csv.t = <fun>
```

To be explicit. What I typed once in the toplevel was:

```
#use "topfind";;
#require "csv";;
Csv.load;; (* or anything else that uses Csv *)
```

Comment: thanks for that : Csv works fine from the toplevel. Still I cannot compile my program bundle where I modified the module compute.ml with the following code 'let data = Csv.load "foo.csv" in' The faulty compilation command (even with -linkall at the end) is 'ocamlopt.opt -warn-error A unix.cmxa argl.cmx lock.cmx def.cmx buff.cmx mut.cmx secure.cmx bbar.cmx ute.cmx utd.cmx base.cmx check.cmx compute.cmx mx sassyz.cmx db1link.cmx sassu.cmx -cclib -lunix -o sassy.opt -linkall ' which gives the message "Error: No implementations provided for the following modules: Csv referenced from compute.cmx"

Comment: Try `ocamlfind ocamlopt.opt -package csv -linkall -warn-error A unix.cmxa argl.cmx ... -o sassy.opt`. If you're lucky, `ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind -pkg csv sassyz.native` might also work.

Comment: It looks that I have a wrong installation of libs on my mutualized server: I got the error message: findlib: [WARNING] Interface csv.cmi occurs in several directories: ., /xxx/zzz/sss/htdocs/opt/lib/ocaml/site-lib/csv
findlib: [WARNING] Interface num.cmi occurs in several directories: /xxx/zzz/sss/htdocs/opt/lib/ocaml, .
File "_none_", line 1, characters 0-1:
Error: No implementations provided for the following modules:
         Csv referenced from compute.cmx