# Amending a complex Makefile for installing a library used in one module of an OCaml package

Tags: csv, makefile, ocaml

I need to add the csv module in one module compute.ml of an OCAML package.(see discussion [ocaml hash from mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12350982/ocaml-hash-from-mysql))

Do you know of a simple way to amend the makefile (it is a complex document in my case and I don't think that I can fully rewrite it or switch to ocamlfind install) to enable a compilation without "Unbound value Csv.load" error messages?

ie can I include a new library inside an existing stable Ocaml package?

modified module : compute.ml,

modification;

```
 let data = Csv.load ("foo.csv")
         ....
```

---

error message during compilation :

```
camlp5r ../wserver/pa_macro5.cmo -DUNIX -o compute.ppo compute.ml
ocamlopt.opt -warn-error A -I ../wserver -I ../sally -I +camlp5 -c -impl compute.ppo
File "compute.ml", line 110, characters 13-21:
Error: Unbound value Csv.load
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to tell ocamlopt where to look for csv.cm{i,x} files with the appropriate -I option, like the ones you already have at the end of your command line.
If the library lies in a subdirectory of OCaml's standard library (as given by ocamlc -where), you can use
-I +csv_dir, as is done for camlp5 in your example. Otherwise, you'll have to provide the full path.

Note that this is not the only modification that you'll have to do: you'll also have to add csv.cmx (or .cmxa) on the command line that perform the final link of your application/library.

Comment: thank you, it improves now but I still have error compiling: 'ocamlopt.opt -I /xxx/yyyyy/zzzz/htdocs/opt/lib/ocaml/site-lib/csv -warn-error A  unix.cmxa argl.cmx aaa.cmx bbb.cmx ---- yy.cmx compute.cmx toto.cmx -cclib -lunix -o sassy.opt
File "_none_", line 1, characters 0-1:
Error: No implementations provided for the following modules:
         Csv referenced from compute.cmx' IS this better than "Unbound value Csv.load"? Any idea of what I should do to go through it? Many thanks

Comment: This is what I said in the second paragraph: you have to explicitely say that you want to link csv.cmx (or csv.cmxa, depending on whether this is a single module or a library), as well as all other implementations files (unix.cmxa &al). -I merely tells OCaml to seek for those files also in the given directory. This is sufficient for the compilation of a single file, but not for the link phase.

Comment: Actually I tried to but did not find yet how exactly to code this linking. Is it in the makefile? in this makefile, I find:  - a variable that lists all modules SASSY_OBJS=arg.cmo def.cmo ... compute.cmo  ... sassy.cmo that will  be compiled in one (of several) binary and, lower in the makefile,  the following code which looks to me like the command line that you mentionned - sassy.opt: $(SASSY_OBJS:.cmo=.cmx)
 $(OCAMLOPT) $(STATIC) unix.cmxa $(SASSY_OBJS:.cmo=.cmx) $(LIBUNIX) -o sassy.opt

Should I put the reference to csv.cmx there?

Comment: Yes. You should merely consider it as an external library such as unix.cmxa

Comment: Thank you so much Virgile. I eventually made it through the 20-odd places where this module appears in the Makefile. You have been most accurate and helpful.Best regards